# How to record webcam in browser and store video on same page?

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, mediarecorder

I have a simple program where a user records themselves (via their webcam) and that video is stored on the same HTML page. Can anyone let me know how I can go about adding to what I have below to record and save the video?

```
#HTML
<button id="speak_button"></button> #click to start video
    
<div id="circle"><p id="submit_button">Submit</p></div> #click to end video

<video" id="video" width="180" height="140" autoplay muted></video> #where webcam is 

    <video id="second_video" width="180" height="140" controls></video> #where I want recorded video to be 



#JAVASCRIPT
  <script>

    let video = document.getElementById("video");
    let mediaRecorder;
    
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
    .then(function(stream){
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "video/webm"});
        mediaRecorder.ondatavailable = function(event) {

            if (event.data.size > 0) {
                const reader = new window.FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(event.data);
                reader.onloadend = function() {

                    let base64 = reader.result.split('base64,')[1];

                    let recording = document.getElementById('second_video');
                    recording.src = "data:video/webm;base64," + base64;
                    recording.type = "video/webm";
                    recording.play();

                };
            };
        };

  
    });

    document.getElementById("speak_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        mediaRecorder.start();
        stream.record();
    });

    document.getElementById("submit_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        stream.stop();
        var superBuffer = new Blob(recordedChunks);
        document.getElementById("second_video") = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
    });
  
    </script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**

```html
  <main id="container">
    <video id="gum" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="recorded" playsinline loop></video>

    <section>
      <button id="start">Start camera</button>
      <button id="record" disabled>Record</button>
      <button id="play" disabled>Play</button>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

**main.js code**

```js
let mediaRecorder;
let recordedBlobs;

const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector("span#errorMsg");
const recordedVideo = document.querySelector("video#recorded");
const recordButton = document.querySelector("button#record");
const playButton = document.querySelector("button#play");

recordButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (recordButton.textContent === "Record") return startRecording();
  stopRecording();
  recordButton.textContent = "Record";
  playButton.disabled = false;
});

playButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, { type: "video/webm" });
  recordedVideo.src = null;
  recordedVideo.srcObject = null;
  recordedVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
  recordedVideo.controls = true;
  recordedVideo.play();
});

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
}

function startRecording() {
  recordedBlobs = [];
  let options = { mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus" };
  try {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Exception while creating MediaRecorder:", e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ${JSON.stringify(
      e
    )}`;
    return;
  }
  recordButton.textContent = "Stop Recording";
  playButton.disabled = true;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => console.log(event);
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start();
  console.log("MediaRecorder started", mediaRecorder);
}

function stopRecording() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
}

document.querySelector("button#start").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true,
    });
    recordButton.disabled = false;
    window.stream = stream;
    const gumVideo = document.querySelector("video#gum");
    gumVideo.srcObject = stream;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("navigator.getUserMedia error:", e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `navigator.getUserMedia error:${e.toString()}`;
  }
});
```